# How to take Center to Bottom space of a relative layout?

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

How to design a layout so that it will take center to bottom space of a relative layout.

```
|--------------------------|
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|--------------------------|
|            |             |
|      this will be        |
|       content            |
|            |             |
|            |             |
|--------------------------|

<RelativeLayout>[another_layout should be here]</RelativeLayout>
```

so **another_layout** will start from the middle of the RelativeLayout and fill up to bottom of that layout.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap your content in a linear layout which will be inside your relative layout then set   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true".

Comment: Actually layout_alignParentBottom wont work. may be my layout picture confused you. my layout structure is like this 
<RelativeLayout>[Content here.....]</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Does it mean you want your content to be somewhere in middle of the screen?

Comment: yes, say I want a LinearLayout. which will start at the middle of the screen and its height will be half of the screen height.

Answer (score 2):

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Invisible View that will hold the position -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/stub"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <!-- Content below -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/stub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/something" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is RelativeLayout your top level element?  If so, why not use a LinearLayout with `layout_weight` parameters and then make just the top a `RelativeLayout`?  That seems way more logical than hacking it below a view that you have centered.  The layout would look something like this.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="stuff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <!-- All the stuff that would have been above the center before -->
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <!-- All the stuff that would have been below the center before -->
    </RelativeLayout>
```

IMO that's a cleaner solution